# Failure of Abel's and Dirichlet's test?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Do Abel's test and Dirichlet's test fail in integrals like $\int_0^\infty x^{1/2}e^{-x}$ since $x^{1/2}$ is not convergent in the interval? If I am wrong please correct me !

Comment: I don't see what you mean. $\int_0^1 x^{-1/2}e^{-x}dx$ converges because $\int_0^1 x^{-1/2}dx$ converges, and $\int_1^\infty x^{-1/2}e^{-x}dx$ converges because $\int_1^\infty e^{-x/2}dx$ converges

Comment: It's x^(1/2) and limit 0 to infinity . x^(1/2) diverges

Comment: It doesn't change anything : $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^a e^{-x/2} = 0$ so there is a $C$ such that for $x > 1 $ : $|x^a e^{-x}| < C e^{-x/2}$ and $\int_1^\infty |x^a e^{-x}|dx <\int_1^\infty C e^{-x/2}dx$ converges

Answer (score 0):

Abel's test states that if

- $f$ is continuous at $[a,+\infty)$
- $f$ positive and decreasing.
- $\exists M\geq 0\;:\;\forall x\in [a,+\infty)$

$$ \;\;|\int_a^x g(t)dt|\leq M$$

then $\int_a^{+\infty}f(t)g(t)dt$ converges.

for example $\int_1^{+\infty}\sin(t)e^{-t}dt$ is convergent but

$\int_1^{+\infty}\sin(t)dt$ is not.